# How to Prefix Checking comment in Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

is it possible to Prefix/Pre-fill the Check-in comment with some static text automatically during check in ?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any setting provided for this feature by default in VS2015. Check-in comment is used to provide some useful information about the changes. Enter static text comments does not make sense.

If you indeed want this feature, you can [create a source control plugin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166413.aspx) to achieve this feature.

Comment: I am not for putting static comment but put some static prefix to the comment, the rest of the comment will be filled by the user.

Comment: @NaunihalSidhu This does make sense. However the answer is still to create a your own source control plugin.